# Task Scheduler, scheduling vbs script

Tags: vbscript, menu, task, scheduler

I 've created an application with Visual Basic, containing a menu bar. Using a menu bar in the application, I can start VB scripts, which works fine.

The next step is to schedule the tasks daily, so I don't have to manually start the scripts.

I would like to use the Task Scheduler to perform the tasks daily and wrote an .vbs script which I scheduled in the Task Scheduler. Testing the script by manually starting the task from Task Scheduler works. But when scheduled (eg for the next morning) it fails: the program is started, but the next step is not performed.. I'am using a laptop, powered at all times, sleeping mode is off, Windows10

My vbs script:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys("{F13}") 
WScript.Sleep 10*1000 '10 sec
WshShell.Run  "C:\360_Stuurprogramma\bin\Debug\360_Stuurprogramma.exe"
WScript.Sleep 5*1000 '5 sec
WshShell.AppActivate """360 Applicatie"" -p1 -c"
WScript.Sleep 20*1000
wshShell.SendKeys "^S"
WScript.Sleep 20*60*1000 '20 min, maximum time needed to perform the job
WshShell.Run "taskkill /f /im 360_Stuurprogramma.exe", , True
```

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63424337/how-to-open-notepad-text-file-and-keep-on-top-of-all-other-windows-until-i-close?answertab=active#tab-top) perhaps help you to make a scheduled task !

Answer (score 0):

Only programs with a foreground GUI can set the active window. A program started by the active window has **two seconds to show a GUI** to become the foreground window. The full rules are here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow
NB Task Scheduler will never be the foreground window.

> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A
> process can set the foreground window only if one of the following
> conditions is true:
>
> •The process is the foreground process.
>
> •The process was started by the foreground process.
>
> •The process received the last input event.
>
> •There is no foreground process.
>
> •The process is being debugged.
>
> •The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start
> Screen.
>
> •The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
>
> •The foreground lock time-out has expired (see
> SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
>
> •No menus are active.
>
> An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user
> is working with another window. Instead, Windows flashes the taskbar
> button of the window to notify the user.